# Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics migration asking a dSYMs file

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have downloaded the dSYMs file from iTunes and uploaded the file to Firebase. But, after I got upload successful, and I am switching to dashboard tab, again it is saying that dSYM file is missing. How to resolve the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try finding via terminal:

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"
```

And then upload it to firebase.

**Edit:**
As @Mike pointed out: You can also run `dwarfdump -u <PathToDsym>` to confirm that the UUID of the dSYM being uploaded matches the one reported as missing

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. You can also run dwarfdump -u <PathToDsym> to confirm that the UUID of the dSYM being uploaded matches the one reported as missing.